# trouble getting carrierwave to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am not sure if the image uploads just aren't saving or if I am saving them in the wrong place or what's wrong..  right now when I generate the image tag with this code:

```
<%= image_tag @photo.image_url.to_s %>
```

it just throws a routing error:

```
No route matches "/images"
```

am I suppose to set up this route?..  I was following the tut on railscasts.org
anyway here is some more relevant code:

```
<%= form.file_field :image %> #in the form

mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader  #in the model Photo

#in the image_uploader file
def store_dir
"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

#also nothing special going on in the controller
def create
@photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])

respond_to do |format|
  if @photo.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@photo, :notice => 'Photo was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @photo, :status => :created, :location => @photo }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @photo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Does it create an object without problems? It just throws an error @ photos#show?

Comment: thats correct and it doesn't show a runtime error since i did .to_s but it sees the image as nil i guess but it does create a link .... /images/1823474 or w/e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here's how i fixed it..  I thought this was automatic, but it wasn't.

```
#in create method and update method and you good :]
@photo.image = params[:file]
```